# Issue With Multiple Windows In Processing

Tags: processing

I have a very simple sketch that opens multiple windows, like so:

```
void setup(){
  size(100,100);
  noLoop();
}
void keyPressed(){
  String[] args={"Secondary window!"};
  SecondWindow window=new SecondWindow();
  PApplet.runSketch(args, window);
}

class SecondWindow extends PApplet{
  void setup(){
    size(100,100);
    background(~0);
    noLoop();
  }
  void keyPressed(){
    exit();
  }
}
```

However, there is an issue: How can I close *just* child window? Pressing the [X] on the child window closes both the parent and child sketch, and the function `exit()` does the same.

Is there a method to close *only* the child applet? The [PApplet documentation](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/index.html?processing/core/PApplet.html) does not list any methods that seem to do this!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `surface` variable gives you access to the underlying window. You can call `surface.setVisble(false)` to hide the window.

```
void setup(){
  size(100,100);
  noLoop();
}
void keyPressed(){
  String[] args={"Secondary window!"};
  SecondWindow window=new SecondWindow();
  PApplet.runSketch(args, window);
}

class SecondWindow extends PApplet{
  void setup(){
    size(100,100);
    background(~0);
    noLoop();
  }
  void keyPressed(){
    surface.setVisible(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
However, if the user accidentally presses the [X] button (which would be natural to hide a window) it would still close the whole sketch, parent and child. Is there a way to disable the [X] or change its functionality?

Comment: @Fuzzyzilla Sure, you need to get to the underlying `JFrame` (you can get to it through the `getNative()` function) and then call the `setDefaultCloseOperation()` function.

Comment: Thanks! The setVisible() function works great, but the setDeafaultCloseOperation() solution does not.
Calling the function seems to have no effect!

Comment: @Fuzzyzilla What parameter are you passing into it? When are you calling it?

Comment: Woops! Realized I was making a mistake and that it was not being called. However, now I'm having another issue: Processing doesn't use JFrame! Instead, the renderers use ResizeableCanvas and SmoothCanvas!

Comment: @Fuzzyzilla I believe the default renderer does indeed use `JFrame`. You just have to cast it.

Comment: Tried that, that's were the error comes in. None of the default renderers seem to use it...

Comment: @Fuzzyzilla Please be more specific than saying you tried it and got an error: what exactly did you try? What exact error did you get? Note that the `SmoothCanvas` is one step removed from the `JFrame`. Please look through the docs and the source to see how to get to the `JFrame`, and if you're still stuck please post a new question in its own post and I'll be happy to help you out. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Here's what I did: `((JFrame)surface.getNative()).setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);` which throws a cast error no matter what renderer is used. I cannot find docs on the classes used. :(

Comment: @Fuzzyzilla Processing is open source. [Here](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/awt/PSurfaceAWT.java) is the source for the `PSurfaceAWT` class. Notice it uses a `JFrame`. If you have any other questions please post them in their own post, as comments are not meant for discussions like this.